# Mysql duplecating results

Tags: php, mysql, cross-join

I'm making a invoice script but my query is returning al my entries mulpiple times when i fetch them.

this is my code:

```
$query      =   "   SELECT d.Quantity, d.ProductID, p.ProductName, d.UnitPrice, d.Discount
                            FROM customers AS c, orders AS o, order_details AS d, products AS p
                            WHERE o.OrderID = '10248'
                            AND o.OrderID = d.OrderID
                            AND d.ProductID = p.ProductID
                        ";

        $result     =   mysql_query($query);

        $table      =   '';

        while($row  =   mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $table  .=  '<tr>';
            $table  .=  '<td>' . $row['Quantity'] . '</td>';
            $table  .=  '<td>' . $row['ProductID'] . '</td>';
            $table  .=  '<td>' . $row['ProductName'] . '</td>';
            $table  .=  '<td>' . $row['UnitPrice'] . '</td>';
            $table  .=  '<td>' . $row['Discount'] . '</td>';
            $table  .=  '<td>' . (100 - $row['Discount']) / 100 * $row['UnitPrice'] . '</td>';
            $table  .=  '</tr>';
        }
```

this is, a part, of what it returns.

```
Quantity    ProductID   ProductName     UnitPrice   Discount    Subtotal
12  11  Queso Cabrales  14.0000 0   14
10  42  Singaporean Hokkien Fried Mee   9.8000  0   9.8
5   72  Mozzarella di Giovanni  34.8000 0   34.8
12  11  Queso Cabrales  14.0000 0   14
10  42  Singaporean Hokkien Fried Mee   9.8000  0   9.8
5   72  Mozzarella di Giovanni  34.8000 0   34.8
12  11  Queso Cabrales  14.0000 0   14
10  42  Singaporean Hokkien Fried Mee   9.8000  0   9.8
5   72  Mozzarella di Giovanni  34.8000 0   34.8
12  11  Queso Cabrales  14.0000 0   14
10  42  Singaporean Hokkien Fried Mee   9.8000  0   9.8
5   72  Mozzarella di Giovanni  34.8000 0   34.8
```

while it sould only return 3 entries.

anny toughts?

Comment: Learn how to join multiple tables. There are many ways of how joins can be performed, one way (yours) is to combine each element with each other and vice-versa (Cross-Table or Cross-Join, also Cartesian-Join for missing joins), that's why you get that many results. See [Using MySQL, Joins](http://www.keithjbrown.co.uk/vworks/mysql/mysql_p5.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a Cartesian join:

```
SELECT d.Quantity, 
       d.ProductID, 
       p.ProductName, 
       d.UnitPrice, 
       d.Discount
FROM   **customers AS c,** 
       orders AS o, 
       order_details AS d, 
       products AS p
WHERE  o.OrderID = '10248'
AND    o.OrderID = d.OrderID
AND    d.ProductID = p.ProductID
```

You need to include a join to customers, or drop that table from the SQL.

Comment: Tnx DB, totaly forgot to remove the from the query. Had customer info in before but removed it. Stuipid of me that i didn't see that. TNX!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a join for customers table. Rather of you are not using any columns from customer table, you may safely remove the table from `FROM` clause:

```
$query  = "SELECT d.Quantity, d.ProductID, p.ProductName, d.UnitPrice, d.Discount
               FROM orders AS o, order_details AS d, products AS p
                   WHERE o.OrderID = '10248'
                   AND o.OrderID = d.OrderID
                   AND d.ProductID = p.ProductID";
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns a row for each customer, because entries from customers table is not constrained in any way at all. I am not sure about your table schema but you should add something like:

```
AND c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
```

to your WHERE clause.